# Python Error TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Tags: arcpy, typeerror

New to python and I keep running into this error

[image: HELP PLEASE THE CODE IS HERE]

Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 5, in 
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: Just change `"OBJECTID = " + row[0]` into `"OBJECTID = " + str(row[0])`

Comment: Please don't use screenshots to show code and exceptions. Copy and paste it in as text, then highlight/select it and use the `{}` button to format as `code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your value in row[0] is an integer, but you are trying to combine (concatenate) it with a string (text). 
You can fix this by temporarily casting row[0] as a string using the built in str() method.

Try this:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_mangement(Fitting, "fcLyr", "OBJECTID = "+ str(row[0]))
```

Or you could use the format method to insert the integer directly into the query string:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Fitting, "fcLyr", "OBJECTID = {}".format(row[0]))
```